# Linux: cat with separators among files

Tags: linux, command, cat

In Linux if you type cat *, you will get something like this:

line1 from file1
line2 from file1
line1 from file2
line1 from file3
line2 from file3
line3 from file3

What I would like is to display a separator among files. Something like this:
line1 from file1
line2 from file1
XXXXXXXXXXXX
line1 from file2
XXXXXXXXXXXX
line1 from file3
line2 from file3
line3 from file3

Is that easily possible with a one-liner easy to type by heart?

Answer (score 54):

If you're not too fussy about the appearance of the separator:

```
tail -n +1 *
```

Comment: This is great! I am surprised how your command is different from tail -n 1 *. I can't either find any mention of the effect of +1 (rathen than 1) in the man page.

Comment: `tail -n X` shows the last X lines. `tail -n +X` starts at line X *beginning at 1*, i.e., it shows all but the first (X-1) lines.

Comment: Ah, now I can see that in the man page. I overlooked it. Great, thanks a bunch

Comment: Similar solutions are in this article: http://everythingsysadmin.com/2012/09/unorthodoxunix.html

Comment: Sorry for the bad comment, but this is awesome. Thank you, @Gilles

Comment: At least for some cases, this is the perfect separator...

Answer (score 19):

`cd /to/your/directory; for each in *; do cat $each; echo "XXXXXXXXXXX"; done`

Comment: beat me to it :-)

Comment: Still the solution provided by Gilles is impressively short!

Comment: Wow. works wonder. Helped me concatenate a folder of JSONs

Answer (score 15):

```
awk 'FNR==1 && NR!=1 {print "XXXXXXXXXXXX"}{print}' *
```

Or

```
awk 'FNR==1 {print "XXXXXX", FILENAME, "XXXXXX"}{print}' *
```

Or

```
awk 'FNR==1 {print "XXXXXX File no. " ++count, "XXXXXX"}{print}' *
```

Using only Bash (no `cat`):

```
for file in *; do printf "$(<"$file")\nXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"; done
```

*Edit:*

In AWK 4:

```
awk 'BEGINFILE {print "XXXXXXXXXXXX"}{print}' *
```

You can use any separator such as the ones in the other examples in this answer. If you want the separator at the end of each file, change `BEGINFILE` to `ENDFILE`. It can still appear at the beginning of the script since it's a conditional (rather than implying execution order)..

Comment: +1 for awk!  I swear it can do anything...